# GAE task queue only processes 6 tasks per minute

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I've been using GAE for many years now, and I'm currently experiencing a very frustrating situation with the task queue (now Cloud Tasks).

I submit about 5-30 tasks per minute, and until a couple days ago, everything was working fine.

Now, my task queue only executes 6 tasks per minute regardless of how many tasks are waiting to be executed. As a result, I'll get tasks executed hours late.

Is there a way for me to increase the rate of task execution?

=== EDIT ===

I think I know what is going on now...  The page that lists your queues indicates that my queue has an enforced rate of 0.1/sec which comes out to 6 per minute.

I'm pretty sure the reason is that on Sunday my app exceeded its daily spending limit and stopped working for about 3 hours.  I increased my spending limit so everything has been fine since then.

I opened an issue with Google to get my rate increased.  I hope they respond quickly.  This is quite annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Check the GAE logs, is it returning 5xx errors? If so Cloud Tasks will slow down the rate that it sends tasks [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/common-pitfalls#backoff_errors_and_enforced_rates).

Comment: It hasn't been since Sunday (see my updated question), but I think outage on Sunday caused the rate throttling. :(